# Android factory reset package name setup?

Tags: android, adb, samsung-mobile

After doing factory reset on my Samsung S3 mini there is a setup screen page where I can select language, then configure wifi, google account and so on.
What is the package name of this setup ? (it's not /system/app/SetupWizard.apk which is only for setup google account)

Answer (score 0):

package name Samsung setup wizard com.sec.android.app.SecSetupWizard, apk file /system/app/SecSetupWizard.apk (SetupWizard.apk is only for google account). After the factory reset this package is disabled, to start it again manually do:
1) adb shell pm enable com.sec.android.app.SecSetupWizard/.SecSetupWizardActivity (root privillege)
2) adb shell am start -n com.sec.android.app.SecSetupWizard/.SecSetupWizardActivity